# testing router gets confused in two controllers with same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

There are two controllers in same name, one in the root module and other in a folder/diff module. The functional test for each of these controllers runs properly independently. But in a suite they fail in routing errors.
How can this problem be fixed?

```
namespace :plan do
    resources :apps, :controller => 'proposals', :as => 'proposals', :path => 'proposals' do
    member do
        ...
    end
    # /app/controllers/plan/qandas_controller
    resources :qandas do
        collection do
        get 'post_new'
        post 'post'
        post 'reply'
        end
        member do
        get 'reply_new'
        post 'post'
        post 'reply'
        get 'edit'
        patch 'update'
        delete 'destroy'
        end
    end
end
resources :apps do
    member do
        ...
    end
    # /app/controllers/qandas_controller
    resources :qandas do
    collection do
        get 'post_new'
        post 'post'
        post 'reply'
    end
    member do
        get 'reply_new'
        post 'post'
        post 'reply'
        get 'edit'
        put 'update'
        delete 'destroy'
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you please post a code sample from your routes file?

Answer (score 0):

Create folder root and folder diff in your test unit.

Comment: I already have the test units in same path pattern as in controllers.